# How do I sort a 2d string array by a specific column's values in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

I have the following 2d array that I get/create from an external .txt file.

```
string accountsArr[5][7] = {
  "bham@gnet.com", "Blake", "Ham", "squid62", "1987", "U", "Teacher",
  "jdark@att.net", "Jim", "Dark", "gymrat32", "1985", "A", "Master",
  "hgreen@lakes.net", "Hannah", "Green", "flower22", "2007", "U", "Apprentice",
  "tsmith@dna.com", "Tom", "Smith", "tuna20", "2000", "U", "Teacher",
  "jarrow@pnet.com", "James", "Arrow", "ahoy10", "2005", "U", "Apprentice"
};
```

I need to sort this array based on the "last name" column (column index 2 for each row), so I basically end up with:

```
string accountsArr[5][7] = {
  "jarrow@pnet.com", "James", "Arrow", "ahoy10", "2005", "U", "Apprentice",
  "jdark@att.net", "Jim", "Dark", "gymrat32", "1985", "A", "Master",
  "hgreen@lakes.net", "Hannah", "Green", "flower22", "2007", "U", "Apprentice",
  "bham@gnet.com", "Blake", "Ham", "squid62", "1987", "U", "Teacher",
  "tsmith@dna.com", "Tom", "Smith", "tuna20", "2000", "U", "Teacher"
};
```

How would I do this, programmatically? Using `std::sort` isn't working. I keep getting `use of undeclared identifier sort`.

```
int n = sizeof(accountsArr[0]) / sizeof(accountsArr[0][0]);
std::sort(accountsArr, accountsArr + n);
```

UPDATE: I need/want to know how to do this on a primitive string array specifically (no vectors, structs, etc).

Comment: Did you try using `std::sort`? Do you know how to use it, in C++? Are there examples of `std::sort` in your C++ textbook that you can look at? Is there anything specific about sorting that you're unsure about?

Comment: Why not create a `struct` for each of these fields and then overload `operator <`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The problem is my textbook doesn't seem to go into 2D arrays. It shows a lot of examples for 1d arrays with only numbers, which is much simpler than the problem i'm currently trying to solve.

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally different about sorting a one dimension array, a two dimension array, or a 42 dimension array. The basic principles are all the same. Unfortunately, we don't write code for other people on stackoverflow.com. You need to show your attempt to sort your array, and explain what your ***specific*** issue is.

Comment: 1. Create a structure (or class) for an entry. 2. transform that raw array into a proper `vector` over your entry type. (Situations in where one should prefer a raw array over proper containers are rare.) 3. overload `operator <` for your structure. 4. call `std::sort` on the vector.

Comment: You cannot realistically expect someone else to already have written the same exact sort you need to use here, so you can simply copy it, without needing to understand how it works. No two C++ programs are alike. They are all different. This is why it is necessary to ***understand*** the underlying algorithms, and how to use `std::sort`. Then you can use your knowledge and understanding of C++'s `std::sort` algorithm in order to implement it for your use case. But, like I said, if you are expecting someone on stackoverflow.com to write your code for you, you'll have to wait for a while...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Dude, I can't find single example anywhere of sorting a primitive 2d array of strings based on a specific column's values. If there was an example somewhere that was even close, I wouldn't be asking on here, now would I? I'm not new to programming, but I am new to C++ and sorting is definitely much more involved and complicated in C++ than I've used in any languages before this. `std::sort` doesn't seem to play well with a primitive 2d string array, as I keep getting errors.

Comment: Did I ever claim you could find it? I said exactly the opposite: you are unlikely to find someone else who happen to have written the same exact sort. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. Trying to implement something in C++ by searching for someone else doing the same thing, and copying it without having to learn the underlying principles, is not going to work. You need to ***learn*** how sorting works, in C++, how `std::sort` works, and then figuring out how to ***make it work*** with your arrays. There is no instant gratification in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out by doing a "bubble sort". Here's how I implemented it. Hopefully this can help someone else who's having trouble finding any examples of sorting with 2d arrays by a specific column:

```
int rows = 5;
int col = 7;
string accountsArr[rows][col] = {
  "bham@gnet.com", "Blake", "Ham", "squid62", "1987", "U", "Teacher",
  "jdark@att.net", "Jim", "Dark", "gymrat32", "1985", "A", "Master",
  "hgreen@lakes.net", "Hannah", "Green", "flower22", "2007", "U", "Apprentice",
  "tsmith@dna.com", "Tom", "Smith", "tuna20", "2000", "U", "Teacher",
  "jarrow@pnet.com", "James", "Arrow", "ahoy10", "2005", "U", "Apprentice"
};

//do a bubble sort
for(int maxElement = rows - 1; maxElement > 0; maxElement--){
  for(int i = 0; i < maxElement; i++){
    //if current row "last name" column is > the next row "last name" column, swap them
    if(theAccounts[i][2] > theAccounts[i + 1][2]){
      std::swap(theAccounts[i], theAccounts[i + 1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It technically works, but you use naive bubble sort that has O(N²) complexity. Not that problematic for a small set of data. But in any case, totally unnecessary. `std::sort` is a thing.

Comment: Would be nice if it was more clear in documentation or my textbook that the `std::sort` function requires so much extra work in order to get a sort to work. I'm specifically working with a primitive string array and needed to be able to sort that, as is.

Comment: What you call extra work is what you should have done in any case, even if you would not use `std::sort`. A key feature of good code is readability. Will you remember in a year that the third entry in a row is the last name? Especially when the array is not hard-coded but read in from a file? Also, do you always have exactly five rows? If it can be dynamic, do you really want the hassle with dynamic memory allocation (requiring you to `delete` it later)? When you write big algorithms and put specific algorithms in a function, do you really want arrays decayed to pointers as arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a better way to approach your problem, using `std::sort`

First, create a proper structure for your data. I'll simplify your entries a bit. We also already implement `operator<` for this, as we need it later.

```
struct Person
{
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    string email;

    Person(const string& first_name, const string& last_name, const string& email) :
        first_name(first_name), last_name(last_name), email(email) {}

    bool operator<(const Person& other) const { return last_name < other.last_name; }
};
```

C++ is meant to be an object-oriented language, and if you have any sort of regularly structured data, it should be at least a structure. As we have no need to encapsulate, with there being no way to render an object invalid, we can keep it a structure, otherwise we'd go for a class.

Raw array are usually not a good way to store data. The only good reason for using one is when things have to be hyper-optimized for speed. Therefore, we now convert your raw array into a proper container:

```
vector<Person> persons;
persons.reserve(rows); // <-- reserve allows for the memory to be properly pre-allocated
for(size_t i=0; i<rows; i++)
{
    persons.push_back(Person(accountsArr[i][1], accountsArr[i][2], accountsArr[i][0]));
}
```

Now that we have a proper container over a structure that defines `operator<`, all we have left to do is to call `std::sort`:

```
std::sort(persons.begin(), persons.end());
```

Done.

We could furthermore think about creating a class `Persons` that handles all of this, having a method `read_file(const string& file)` which reads the data, puts it into a member vector and then sorts it.

In any case, for the future, if people tell you to use `std::sort`, it won't hurt to search for a tutorial on how it is used. It has some other functionality to offer. Go for a description of it, like as in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort, and make sure to read and understand everything in it.
In this case, you were able to write a naive bubblesort, but when you program, you want to do as little as possible yourself. The STL functions are most likely more effective (your sorting is in O(N²), but sorting can be done in O(NlogN)) and is tested over and over again (creating a bug happens so easily).

Also, the STL has a [built in `std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), since you defined one yourself in your custom bubble sort.

In any way, consider putting some future code of yours on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Edit: as you wrote something about "unidentified identifier sort" in your question, you need to include headers if you want functionality. In case of `std::sort`, the right inclue is `#include <algorithm>`.